# MacGyvered chlorine gas protection

Tags: safety, halides, chemical-weapons

I was watching [Periodic Video's chlorine video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXCfBl4rmh0&index=17&list=PL7A1F4CF36C085DE1), which discusses chlorine's ferocity in stripping electrons whenever possible, and the professors mentioned its consequent use in [WWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I) as a chemical agent. This got me thinking, if I were in that situation (say Syria if they decided to go old-school or a chemical leak), what could I do to protect myself against gaseous chlorine using the chemistry of everyday materials around me?

I imagine a wet towel won't help much to prevent the chlorine from getting in my lungs. Are there any easily obtainable substances I could safely breath through that would neutralize the chlorine? Or are there any (realistic) MacGyver solutions to quickly building a semi-functional gas mask? Just kinda curious what could be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interestingly, the British had such a solution in WWI: the [Hypo Helmet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypo_helmet). This was simply a bag soaked in sodium thiosulfate solution and worn over the head.  Thiosulfate reduces chlorine (and halogens generally) to chloride (halide) ions:

$\ce{2 S2O3^{2−} + Cl2 → S4O6^{2−} + 2 Cl^{−}}$

As the article notes, this was not the best solution, but I think it fits your criteria for rough and ready protection.

Comment: Very interesting! Any ideas how to MacGyver some sodium thiosulfate from everyday chemicals?

Comment: It might surprise you that hobbyists still develop black & white film. Hypo is used to "fix" the final print after developing. So it's easy to get. It's also sold to de-chlorinate water. It might not be everyday, but it's readily available.